# Dynamically include a script Tag in the head/body of index.html

Tags: angular

I'm trying to include the Jira Helpcenter widget they offer on their site, in our app.

Script looks like this.

```html
<script data-jsd-embedded data-key="<<key goes in here>>" data-base-url="https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com" src="https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com/assets/embed.js"</script>
```

I have included it directly in the index.html file, it works, and I can see that an iframe is created through the script like below.

```html
<iframe scrolling="no" name="JSD widget" id="jsd-widget" style="height: 80px; width: 70px; position: fixed; border: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 2147483647; transition: height 0s ease 0s;"></iframe>
```

However I want to make it more dynamic and not sure if placing it directly into the index.html is good practice.
So I opted to use a service and make use of renderer2 class.

```js
import { Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ScriptLoaderService {
  private renderer: Renderer2;
  constructor(private router: Router, private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
  loadScript() {
    const scriptUrl = "https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com/assets/embed.js";
    const dataBaseUrl = "https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com";
    const dataKey = "<<some key in here>>";

    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(script, 'data-jsd-embedded', '' );
    this.renderer.setAttribute(script, 'data-key', dataKey);
    this.renderer.setAttribute(script, 'data-base-url', dataBaseUrl);
    script.src = scriptUrl;
    script.defer = true;
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, script);
    console.log("-> script", script);
  }
}
```

I use the service as soon as the user logs in and gets to the dashboard. Script is placed into the head however I have two issues:

1. The iframe doesn't get generated, Im guessing cause the script is not executed?
2. The script gets added everytime I navigate to the dashboard page, or refresh..I guess cause Im not checking if it's already there. How can I check if a tag in the head exists already?
   Any help is much appreciated :slight_smile:

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for it? I try to do the same but the script doesn't get executed as it seems.

Comment: Same, any updates/tips?